# multiline into single line and output to logger

Tags: sed, awk

I have a log file where data entries are as follows Each entry starts with time:

```
time: 20170509123420
dn: uid=abc,ou=People,dc=test,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: passwordAllowChangeTime

replace: passwordExpirationTime

replace: passwordRetryCount

replace: pwdpolicysubentry

replace: modifiersname
modifiersname: uid=admin,ou=administrators,ou=topologymanagement,o=netscaperoot
replace: modifytimestamp
modifytimestamp: 20170509113420Z

time: 20170509123621
dn: cn=nsPwPolicyContainer,dc=test,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: add
objectClass: nsContainer
objectClass: top
cn: nsPwPolicyContainer
creatorsName: uid=admin,ou=administrators,ou=topologymanagement,o=netscaperoot
modifiersName: uid=admin,ou=administrators,ou=topologymanagement,o=netscaperoo
```

Now I want to print as single line, only the entries between the time:. For eg, after time :, I want to print all records as single line, so in my case, it should print like

```
time: 20170509123420 dn: uid=abc,ou=People,dc=test,dc=example,dc=com changetype: modify replace: passwordAllowChangeTime - replace: passwordExpirationTime - replace: passwordRetryCount - replace: pwdpolicysubentry - replace: modifiersname modifiersname: uid=admin,ou=administrators,ou=topologymanagement,o=netscaperoo t - replace: modifytimestamp modifytimestamp: 20170509113420Z
```

I have tried with below commend, It's displaying on screen but when try to  redirect/append it's not working.

```
tailf /var/log/dirsrv/slapd-ldap/audit | awk '/^time:/ {if (NR!=1)print"";printf $0}{printf $0}END{print"";}' | logger
```

Is there any command for doing this?

Comment: It seems the formatting of your question is wrong. This makes it hard to read. Please try to fix it.

Comment: The whole point is using `>` instead of `|`. because you want to *put text into a **file*** instead of *passing it to a **command***. you should make clear what *logger* is.

Comment: logger is the command, which forward the logs to messages log file

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
awk '/^time:/ { print "\n" } { printf "%s ",$0 }' /var/log/dirsrv/slapd-ldap/audit > logger
```

Comment: Nice solution, but it appears the OP wants to tail from the audit file and skip the first newline so I'd write `tailf /var/log/dirsrv/slapd-ldap/audit | awk 'NR>1 && /^time:/ { print "\n" } { printf "%s ",$0 }' > logger`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's I have tried already. It will display on screen only, it won't redirect to file. Issue also same.